# Value of Boolean in not changing from false to true

Tags: java, boolean

The problem is, I have to print `NO` if given array have any Even element and `YES` if all elements is Odd,
but if my code print `NO` after that it will only print `NO`.

> **Given**
>
> `t` = Total test case
>
> `n` = Length of each array
>
> and of course `n` elements also

**Input**

```
2
5
1 2 5 4 3
1
7
```

**Output**

```
NO
NO
```

**Expected Output**

```
NO
YES
```

> **Following is My Code**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class dsj {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt();
        while (t-- > 0){
            int n = sc.nextInt();
            boolean k = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                int x = sc.nextInt();
                if (x % 2 == 0) {
                    k = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (k)
                System.out.println("YES");
            else
                System.out.println("NO");
                
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

> **Please tell me what I am doing wrong**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as your application find an even number it breaks the loop, which means it no longer reads the rest of the line.
The next invocation will start where the previous left off and consume that input.

So when the second '2' is read, the inner loop breaks and 'NO' gets printed.
For the next loop the '5' is read which means there should be 5 values to be read. Then the value '4' is read, which is even again, and the code emits 'NO' again. The values 3, 1 and 7 are never consumed.

It works as designed. To better understand, add lots of System.out.println statements, or learn how to use a debugger.

But to answer your question:

The first int specifies how many datasets you want to read.
The first int per dataset specifies how many data values are in the set. The remaining numbers resemble the data set.

Your problem is that when you encounter an even number you do not read the remainder of the dataset, and you program treats the next integers as the specifier of the next dataset's length.
What you need to change is that even when you encountered an even number you have to consume enough integers from your scanner so the dataset is read before you start reading the next.
That change can be as easy as removing the `break`.

Comment: I am so dumb, thanks. In order to avoid traversing whole array I completely forgot rest of elements.

Answer (score 0):

<s>after you print yes or no, you should reset the boolean to true again</s>

EDIT: @Suman Saurabh is correct here

Comment: Bro if boolean is initialized in beginning of loop, it itself get reset.

Comment: this is a good point